# how to check if a mysql user exists in java

Tags: java

I have a code that registers users in mySql and I want it to be able to check if the user already exists before creating it

This is what i have currently

```
@EJB
private UserEJB userEJB;

private User user;


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String firstname = request.getParameter("fname");
        String surname = request.getParameter("sname");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        user = new User(firstname, surname, email, password);
        CreateUser(user);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank You for Registering, Login to continue");
        RequestDispatcher rsd = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
        rsd.forward(request, response);
    }
}


public void CreateUser(User user){
       userEJB.addUser(user);
}
```

Comment: Pleas add more information and code. You are adding users to a table in your database? You are trying to add users to the Users table of MySQL. 
Also Add the code of UserEJB. to check about the database access and use to provide the best response for the case.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post more information. So I will give you a basic idea to achieve what you need.

I will get `email` as a unique field because the same email address can't be there for two users. So your `SQL` query should be something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? // Select all users belongs to the provided email
```

And a example code for your reference,

```
    boolean isAvailable = false;
    String email = request.getParameter("email"); // Get email from a form

    String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?"; // Select all users belongs to the provided email

    try {
            PreparedStatement statement; // Using a preparedStatement to prevent SQL-Injection
            ResultSet resultSet;
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.setString(1, email);
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

            if(resultSet.next()) {
                isAvailable = true;
            } else {
                isAvailable = false;
            }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So if `isAvailable` gives `true` the user is already a registered user in your case. But if `isAvailable` gives `false` the user is not in the database.

Hope this helps you.